# I am trying to add trailing '.' padding a string to a specific length

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I am trying to pad a string that contains product and price.  I have upgraded from MSSQL 2008 TO MSSQL 2017 (EXPRESS).  I am unable to achieve the results that I was getting before.

In MSSQL 2008 I was using the following:

`dbo.String.Padright(rtrim(p.Name_en),30,'.'), p.Price`

Now, MSSQL 2017 this function does not work. I am unable to figure out how to pad with a character.

This is the output I am looking to achieve:

pName....................... 12.00

Comment: What does `does not work` means ? Please elaborate ?

Comment: Does not provide me with the properly formatted results.  "Function not recognized..."

Comment: this is not standard `SQL Server` function. Did you migrate from `2008` ?

Comment: No was a clean install, but pulled scripts that I had saved.

Comment: then you need to migrate that function over

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `right` for leading and `left` for trailing dots functions, i used `space()` function to replicate `.`

```
select right(replace(space(30), space(1), '.') + rtrim(cast(p.Name_en as varchar(max)),30), p.Price
```

**For trailing dots**

```
select left(trim(cast(p.Name_e as varchar(max)))+replace(space(30), space(1), '.'),30)
```

Comment: I get this error "Argument data type text is invalid for argument 1 of rtrim function"

Comment: well you didn't specify the table schema, try casting it to varchar(max)

Comment: `select right(replace(space(30), space(1), '.') + rtrim(cast(p.Name_en as varchar(max))),30), p.Price
from Product p
left outer join ProductCategory pc
 on p.CategoryId = pc.CategoryId
 left outer join ParentCategory parC
 on pc.ParentCategoryId = parc.ParentCategoryId
 where pc.Name_en like 'Bread' `

Comment: ...........White Bread (thick) 2.75
............White Bread (thin) 2.75
...................Brown Bread 2.75
.........Stone Ground WW Bread 2.75
.....................Rye Bread 3.50
.................9 Grain Bread 2.75
.....................Baguettes 2.25
................Hamburger Buns 2.00
..................Dinner Rolls 3.00
...................Cheese Buns 4.50
...................Brown Bread 3.95
..................Garlic Bread 3.50
.....................Croissant 1.50

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(12) = 'pName'
       ,@Price MONEY = 12;

DECLARE @HelpString VARCHAR(30) = REPLICATE('.', 30)

SELECT LEFT(@Name + @HelpString, 30), @Price
```

The idea is simple - concatenate your text with 30 `.` - then get first 30 symbols starting from the left side of the string.